# Unable to install Jenkins on Minikube using Helm due to the permission

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've been trying to install Jenkins by using Helm on Minikube according to the official article

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/

It turns out that I can't bring up the Jenkins Pod,  `kubectl logs -f jenkins-0 -c init -n jenkins`   gives me this error

```
disable Setup Wizard
/var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh: 4: /var/jenkins_config/apply_config.sh: cannot create /var/jenkins_home/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state: Permission denied
```

From my assumption, this issue obviously relates with permission in `Dockerfile`
or it might relates to the defined values in `jenkins-values.yaml`. I've changed some parameters as the recommended values.

```
storageClass: jenkins-pv

serviceAccount:
create: false
name: jenkins
annotations: {}

serviceType: NodePort
```

release detail

```
NAME    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
jenkins jenkins         1               2021-01-04 15:58:00.022465588 +0700 +07 deployed        jenkins-3.0.14  2.263.1
```

is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that for some reason the volume is mounted with not-enough access rights. You can try running your container with the root user. It may solve the issue. Put these lines into your `values.yaml`.

```
runAsUser: 0
fsGroup: 0
```

Comment: Confirmed!This is literally the cause, Cheers!